# Text-wrap and e-mail options in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio

Can anyone kindly tell me whether Microsoft Visual Studio Code has the features of

1. 'text-wrap' of comparison results, and
2. e-mail generation of comparison reports.

If these features are available, then in which version are they present? I am currently using the most basic version. Thanks.

Comment: Your question states Visual Studio Code but you've tagged the question with Visual Studio - these are completely different (like Java and JavaScript)

Comment: Also, what is "most basic version"

Comment: Oops, sorry. Can u refer me to the correct section where i can post this question? I am new to this site...The most basic version = Version 1.50.1 of the software.